# bidirectional_dynamic_rnn function in tensorflow 1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to reproduce the seq2seq model from this repo:
https://github.com/llSourcell/seq2seq_model_live/blob/master/2-seq2seq-advanced.ipynb
I have a probleme with the rnn function  In [13]:
    bidirectional_dynamic_rnn

I get this error:
TypeError: Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'ConcatV2' Op have types [float32, float64] that don't all match.
is it because deprecated function in Tensorflow 1.0, or this is a problem with the script or a problem of deprecation
can someone help

Comment: The error shown in the linked notebook is different than the one you posted. If you do get the one you posted, did you try not to mix `float32` and `float64` as the error says?

Comment: Actually I replaced float64 by float32  and it worked for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont have enough rep to add a comment, have had the same problem.

```
tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, encoder_inputs)
```

will cast you're embeddings to tf.float64, which was what was caussing the concat between float32 and float64 error.
I solved it by replacing above with

```
tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, encoder_inputs)
tf.cast(encoder_inputs_embedded,tf.float32)
```

and also casting the embeddings variable to float32 (assuming its a numpy array).

Comment: Hi @Ola R,  a question regarding the debugging skill :  how you figure out that tf.cast is the solution to this issue ? The error message looks very random to me...

Comment: @SoManyProblems Usually drawing the network and seeing which input fields are the once affecting the place in the graph that triggered an error helps. In this case we have a type error an so forcing the type should help (hence tf.cast).